# Compare 2 views with different number of columns

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 views with different number of columns. 1 of the views has been joined with another view that is why it has additional columns.

The first view has 113 records (View 2), while the updated view (View 1) has 130 columns. I would like to find out the number of records that are extra in View 1
.

```
View 1      View 2
A|B|C|D|E    A|B|C
1 2 3 4 5    1 2 3 
1 2 3 7 8          
3 2 1 4 5    3 2 1
3 2 1 7 8
```

expected result :

```
1 2 3 7 8
3 2 1 7 8
```

Thanks.

Comment: rows or columns?

Comment: Add some sample data and show us the expected result. (As well formatted text.)

Comment: what about a left join to get the result?

Comment: @vkp rows. Not columns!

Comment: you did not provide expected result yet

Comment: @LelioFaieta Won't work as there will be no null field values.

Comment: why `3 2 1 7 8` is in expected result but not `3 2 1 4 5`? what is criteria makes them different?

Comment: Any one of them should be fine @Alex

Comment: that is not how sql or any logic works

Comment: The first view is joined with another view which has extra records for column (B), that is why it is generating extra records. I just want to find those records in column (B) that have extra records. @alex Hope this helps

Comment: you have no condition to detect if record is "extra" or "not extra"

Comment: can we at least be sure that records in view2 are unique?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get that extra records by using 'not in'  or 'not exists' conditions

```
select * from view1 m where not exists (
select 1 from view2 u where  (m.a=u.a and m.b=u.b and m.c=u.c)
```

You can change those conditions as per your requirement

With left join also will get the required result

```
select m.* from view1 m left join view2 u
 (m.a=u.a and m.b=u.b and m.c=u.c)
 where u.a is null and u.b is null and u.c is null
```

Comment: the where clause should be m.a = u.a?

Comment: @Rahul I changed it

Answer (score 0):

You shoul probably refactor your DB schema and data logic.

But just to resolve your weird requirements you can:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/cf2c50/2

```
SELECT t.a, t.b, t.c, t.d, t.e
FROM (
SELECT v1.*, IF(@idx = concat(v1.a,v1.b,v1.c),1,0) `filter`,@idx := concat(v1.a,v1.b,v1.c)
FROM v1
INNER JOIN v2
ON v1.a=v2.a AND v1.b=v2.b AND v1.c=v2.c
ORDER BY v1.a,v1.b,v1.c
) t
WHERE t.`filter`=1;
```

It is not best example of query performance, but it should return expected result.